# Need to re-work script to use jobs for parallel transfer

Tags: powershell, jobs

I have a working script to copy (via SMB) a few files from different locations. Unfortunately, this is taking too long since it is copying one file after the other.

I need to re-work this script to use the jobs and transfer all files in parallel.

I'm relatively new to PowerShell. How can I do this?

The following is my current script:

```
$DATA = Import-Csv -Path F:\TDB_Server.csv -Delimiter ";"
$LOGTIME = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"

   Function LogWrite  {
        Param ([string]$logstring)
        Add-content $LOG -value $logstring
    }

LogWrite ($LOGTIME + "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

    $copyfiles = [scriptblock] {
        Param ($d)
        $DOW = [int] (get-date).DayOfWeek
        $DATE = (Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd")
        $source = "\\$($d.SERVER)\f$\TDB\ZIP_SICH\ZIP$DOW"
        $dest = "F:\system2\$($d.TDB)"
        $LOG = "F:\LOGs\$DATE.log"

        Copy-Item "$source\datum.txt" $destination -PassThru -errorAction SilentlyContinue
        if(-not $?) {LogWrite ($LOGTIME + " - **************** !! Exception!! ********************"}

        Copy-Item "$source\hash_org.txt" $destination -PassThru -errorAction SilentlyContinue
        if(-not $?) {LogWrite ($LOGTIME + " - **************** !! Exception!! ********************"}

        Copy-Item "$source\WinTSzipArchiv.zip" $destination -PassThru -errorAction SilentlyContinue
        if(-not $?) {LogWrite ($LOGTIME + " - **************** !! Exception!! ********************"}

        #alte Daten auf FTP pro NL löschen
        Remove-Item F:\system2\$TDB\* -Force 
        $LOGTIME = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"
        LogWrite ($LOGTIME + " - alte Dateien vom FTP Server gelöscht")

        #Erzeuge datum.txt auf dem NT Server der Niederlassungen
        (get-item $DIR\WinTSzipArchiv.zip).lastWriteTime.ToString() | out-file -encoding ASCII $DIR/datum.txt
        $LOGTIME = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"
        LogWrite ($LOGTIME + " - datum.txt erzeugt auf $TDB / $SERVER")

        # Hash-Werte der Kopierten Datei (WinTSzipArchiv.zip) überprüfen
        # Zuerst generieren wir einen Hash-Wert für die neue kopierte Datei
        $file = "F:\system2\$TDB\WinTSzipArchiv.zip"
        & "C:\Windows\fciv.exe" $file > F:\system2\$TDB\hash_copy.txt

        # Hash-Dateien anpassen und Hash-Werte zum vergleich auslesen
        # hash_org.txt
        $file = "F:\system2\$TDB\hash_org.txt"
        (Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Skip 3) | Set-Content $file
        (([char[]](Get-Content $file -Encoding byte -TotalCount 32)) -join '') | Set-Content $file

        $hash_org = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("F:\system2\$TDB\hash_org.txt")

        # hash_copy.txt
        $file = "F:\system2\$TDB\hash_copy.txt"
        (Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Skip 3) | Set-Content $file
        (([char[]](Get-Content $file -Encoding byte -TotalCount 32)) -join '') | Set-Content $file

        $hash_copy = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("F:\system2\$TDB\hash_copy.txt")

        # Schreiben der Hash-Werte ins Log    
        $LOGTIME = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"
        LogWrite ($LOGTIME + " - Hash_org : $hash_org")
        LogWrite ($LOGTIME + " - Hash_copy: $hash_copy")
    }

    $copyjobs = @()

    ForEach ($d in $DATA) {
        $copyjobs += start-job -scriptblock $copyfiles -ArgumentList $d
    }

    wait-job $copyjobs

    Send-MailMessage -To "mon_tdb@halltabakwaren.de" -Subject "TDB FTP" -From "TDB@halltabakwaren.de" -Body "TDB_Sicherung ist fertig, Logdatei im Anhang" -SmtpServer "exchange02.hall.intern" -Attachments $LOG
    $LOGTIME = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"
    LogWrite ($LOGTIME + " - E-Mail wurde verschickt - ENDE -")
    LogWrite ($LOGTIME + "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33282399/4535033) similar question. You should use search first.

But in brief: run `Start-Job` for each of your Copy-Item, then use `Wait-Job` to wait for copy to complete and `Receive-Job` to gather results (if your copy task returns result).

```
$copyfiles = [scriptblock] {
  Param ($d)
 $DOW = [int] (get-date).DayOfWeek 
 $DATE = (Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd")
 $source = "\\$($d.SERVER)\f$\TDB\ZIP_SICH\ZIP$DOW"
 $dest = "F:\system2\$($d.TDB)"

 Copy-Item "$source\datum.txt" $destination -PassThru -errorAction SilentlyContinue
 if(-not $?) {#write-warning "Replace this with your custom logging"}
 Copy-Item "$source\WinTSzipArchiv.zip" $destination -PassThru -errorAction SilentlyContinue
 if(-not $?) {#write-warning "Replace this with your custom logging"}
 # other files ......
}

$DATA = Import-Csv -Path F:\TDB_Server.csv -Delimiter ";"
$copyjobs = @()

ForEach ($d in $DATA) {
  $copyjobs += start-job -scriptblock $copyfiles -ArgumentList $d
}
wait-job $copyjobs
```

Comment: 10mins difference in posting - as i did search at the time before i posted.
thanks for the infos.

not sure how i can do that sure one of the $copy = copy-item if else

Comment: or do i need to bring all copy-item into one array?

Comment: Updated with your example

Comment: Okay... if i understand this right - please correct me:

- copyjobs defines the actual jobs with the scriptblock of the copy-item
- the jobs are run 
- wait for the jobs to finish
- write the log file

if that is correct, then i don´t have it parallel for all servers, but just the three files definied per server. 

So i don´t really gain anything at the moment. It is the transfer of all server (read out of the csv file) that i need parallel. 

Is there i way i can get that?

Comment: ForEach ($d in $DATA) { - this starts (right at the top, for some reason not well seen due to the copy & paste) the large loop for each item in the csv file. Each line in the csv is a server from which the 3 files are copied. That is what i need parallel.

Comment: sorry if this was not clear in my first description :(

Comment: You need to copy 3 files from remote servers to the server where script is ruining, wright?

Comment: correct, the server is determined via csv import - there are 9 servers at the moment, each have the same share / directory / files and i want to be able to copy all 9 server at once.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have updated my main post, with what i hope incorporates correctly what you have given me into my whole script. Would you give it a quick check that i have not screwed something up?

Comment: There's excessive quote mark in the second logwrite call. And I don't know what you are doing after all copy jobs are done. Maybe all this 'hash calculation' should be performed inside copyfiles scriptblock?

Comment: okay got it, thanks. I think i am safe with the last part since it works in my old script. I am basically getting the hash of the orginal file, sticking that in the logfile and the second hash of the same file after the copy and stick that in the logfile as well - that way i can see that both files (orginal and copied) are the same. (not found a way how to just compare both hash strings and say all is well. :)

Comment: okay, cleaned it up and this is my end script - will be testing it in the next couple of days. thanks again